# querySelector and how to assign it to the variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could you tell me please, now when I got a node ( class ), how do I can to remove it fro the page ?

let randomVariable = document.querySelector(".className");

What is the next step/command? randomVariable.classList.remove(“className”); doesn’t works

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There's no `querySelector()` method defined on `window`, hence it would have to be `document.querySelector()` (or with a `HTMLElement` as target). `document.querySelector()` won't ever return `undefined`. And to query the DOM you would have to use a CSS selector and not only a class name. -> Add a [mcve]

Comment: And why the `jquery-selectors` tag?

Comment: Hey, I’m sorry let me fix this let randomVariable = document.querySelector (“className”); - shows me undefined. 
If I typing document.querySelector(“className”); - shows me a node. How I can to assign it or the variable ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: As already said. [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) does not return `undefined` -> _"Return Value: An `HTMLElement` object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or `null` is returned if there are no matches."_

Comment: Also it would be `".classname"` with a dot if you want a class

Comment: Also, when is this script being called? Are you sure the DOM is ready?

Comment: `let` statement does not "return" anything so the console would display `<• undefined`. If you're playing in console you need to type these two commands: `let randomVariable = document.querySelector(".className"); randomVariable;` or `let randomVariable = document.querySelector(".className"); console.log(randomVariable);`

Comment: But could you explain to me, how to use this let randomVariable = querySelector (“.className”); - all that I want is to I assign this value to the variable and later on I will be able to use my other properties such as classList etc

Comment: SALMAN thank you!! I’m totally beginner in JS..

Comment: But how do I can to remove some class or node from the page then?

Comment: `randomVariable.parentNode.removeChild(randomVariable)` to remove the div

Comment: `randomVariable.classList.remove("className")` to remove the class

Answer (score 0):

`randomVariable.classList.remove(“className”);` will remove class of this element. To removeelement itself use `randomVariable.remove();`
Keep in mind, that if there isn't element of this class this will throw an error, and if there are multiple elements, only first will be removed. To remove everythink:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".className").forEach(x=>x.remove());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand is what you want;

1. there is some element with certain class in DOM
2. you want to search for that element
3. Then you want to reference that to variable
4. Then after doing what eles you need to do remove the element from DOM all together

It is simple work example below;

```js
var toRemove = document.querySelector(".remove");

//one you have that referenced you can do what ever you want
setTimeout(function(){ toRemove.innerHTML = 'I just got changed'; }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ alert('Iam about to be reomved');toRemove.remove(); }, 4000);
```

```html
<p class="remove">Iam first in line and will be referenced and reomved</p>
<p class="remove">I am just dummy line chillin my way through whole drama</p>
```

querySelector is prototyped to document so use document.querySelector
querySelector selects first element it finds where as querySelectorAll will select all the elements it finds in an array format its called collection list.
First returns the node other returns collection list.

Example with query selector all

```js
var toRemove = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");

//one you have the collection list referenced you can do what ever you want but have to loop over each item one by one.
setTimeout(function(){ 
var i;
for (i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
  toRemove[i].innerHTML = 'we just got changed';
}

 }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ alert('we about to be reomved');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
toRemove[i].remove(); 
}
}, 4000);
```

```html
<p class="remove">Iam first in line and will be referenced and reomved</p>
<p class="remove">I am just dummy line chillin my way through whole drama</p>
```

BUT this does not mean reference is gone Js still holds the reference.

```js
var toRemove = document.querySelector(".remove");

//one you have that referenced you can do what ever you want
setTimeout(function(){ toRemove.innerHTML = 'I just got changed'; }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ alert('Iam about to be reomved');toRemove.remove(); }, 4000);


setTimeout(function(){ console.log(toRemove);}, 6000);


//you can add it right back in

setTimeout(function(){ toRemove.innerHTML = 'I going back to DOM yay!!!'; document.body.append(toRemove)}, 8000);
```

```html
<p class="remove">Iam first in line and will be referenced and reomved</p>
<p class="remove">I am just dummy line chillin my way through whole drama</p>
```

Hope it gives you enough ideas as what you can do once you references.